# EditText NullPoint Exception

Tags: android

```
public class LinkActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView;
String[] text = { "robin", "robin", "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin",
        "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin", };
private Button button;
private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int link = bundle.getInt("link");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Right", 200).show();

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(text[link]);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = editText.getText().toString();

            if ((name.equals(text[link]))) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Right", 200).show();
            }

        }
    });
  }

}
```

In this code I have received the position from another Activity.
Finally in this apps I put some name if the name is correct this will show the right Toast.
But when I pressed the ok Button nothing is happened. What is the problem? I don't understand.

2.If this is correct then i want to save it in sharedPrefarance like when i come back in this position this it shows right.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new post about your 2nd question, after you have attempted it and are running into problems.  Keep your posts isolated to 1 issue at a time to get the best results.

Comment: so what really is the problem about the shared preference? save it?

Answer (score 6):

Change this:

```
if (name == text[link]) {
```

to be this:

```
if (name.equals(text[link])) {
```